# Replicated Point Pattern: Get Density Variance Between Replicated Patterns and Subtract from Composite

Tags: r, sf, sp, spatstat

I have written a lengthy code that dissects differently shaped/sized windows into recognizable components (individual cells in the image), gets the point density within each cell, then builds a whole composite based on averages of each cell.

But because the points are randomly distributed via sf::st_sample() within each cell of the composite, there is some variation in the output composites with repeated runs of the code, even though the same information is being fed in.

I want to compare composite patterns under two treatments, but I would like to control for the variation created by my composite-creating code. Is there a way to remove variation in replicated patterns (e.g. I run my composite code on the same data multiple times, then compare the outcomes for variation).

[image: recognizable components]

Here's 100 reps of the composite function overlaid, and a single rep of the composite.

[image]

[image]

Any way to account for the variation before comparing it to another pattern?

(I am sure this is confusing, especially without code, please let me know what needs to be clarified.)

Edit: I am looking to compare the two patterns via spatstat::eval.im(treatment1finalcomposite > treatment2finalcomposite), and I am hoping to remove the background "noise"/variation in each finalcomposite via the methods ya'll suggest.

Comment: I don't think multiple reps of a simulated point pattern based on a cell density grid is a good method for what I think you are trying to do here. You should be directly comparing your point pattern with your cell density. You've also not said what "compare" means. What's your actual substantive question here?

Comment: "Compare" means to see if there is a shift in the patterning of point objects between treatments, using something like eval.im(). Since there is some error/variation in the output of my composite simulation, I'm worried about comparing that with another composite simulation from a different treatment, as the error/variation might be misinterpreted as a true difference due to the treatment. My question is how to avoid that misinterpretation.

Comment: One idea I had was running the simulation multiple times, then getting the mean density and density variance, then using that to compare the two treatments using eval.im().

Comment: I'm trying to figure out which "two patterns" you are trying to compare, and how they relate to the simulated patterns (which are all being generated from the same density grid?).

Comment: Sorry, my description is very unclear. I have a lot of real-data patterns, which are pulled from two different treatments. For example, 30 object patterns in one treatment and 30 object patterns from another experimental treatment. Then, for each treatment, the 30 patterns are condensed down to one "simulated" pattern by applying a density grid to each real-data pattern. So I have 2 simulated patterns, one from each treatment. I want to compare these 2 simulated patterns, seeing how they differ in pattern, while controlling for the random object placement in each cell for the simulated pattern